# Object at different indexes when exporting in json

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, api

It happens that I am creating an object in Node JS and mssq, however some arrays are put in position [0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUYbq.png), [0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iktt.png), and other arrays are put in [0], [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUYbq.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iktt.png), How can I find out what is causing this behavior?

**Behavior 1**

Query

```
var branchOfficesDTO = [];

var branchs = await pool.request().input('idUser', idUser).query(queryGetBranchsByUser);
for (let i = 0; i < branchs.recordset.length; i++) { 
     var categories = await pool.request().input('id', branchs.recordset[i].id).query(queryGetCategoriesByBranch);
     let userDTO = { 
          categories: categories.recordset
     }
     branchOfficesDTO.push(branchOfficeDTO);
}
```

Result

[image]

**Behavior 2**

Query

```
var usersDTOByID = [];
var users = await pool.request().input('id', id).query(queryGetUserById);
for (let i = 0; i < users.recordset.length; i++) { 
     var categories = await pool.request().input('idUser', users.recordset[i].id).query(queryGetCategoriesByUser);
     let userDTO = { categories: categories.recordset }
}
usersDTOByID.push(userDTO);
```

Result

[image]

I need the second behavior, help

Comment: In case 1, `categories` is an array of array. So, it's like: `categories: [[{categoria: 'Academias'}, {categoria: 'Cine'}]];`. In case 2:, it is simply an array of objects. It's like: `categories: [{slug: 'academic', ... categoria: 'Academic...'}, {slug: 'health', ... categoria: 'Salud....'}];`.

Comment: exactly, but, how to set casi 1 like a case 2, if its the same code...

Comment: Several ways are available. May be: Spread the contents of the inner-array when populating the outer-array. Or: use `.flat()` on the outer-array and that will remove the nesting.